# get back stack activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have 2 Activities `ActivityA` & `ActivityB`, if you open `ActivityA` and select anything from it, it will open `ActivityB`, and when you finish `ActivityB` it will go back to `ActivityA`, how can i open `ActivityB` lets say from a notification, and when user finishs it, if there is nothing in back stack I opens `ActivityA`, am asking about the best solution for this, I already have ideas about that, but still not sure if this is the best solution for it.

in `ActivityB`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
```

or I can send a flag from `ActivityA` to `ActivityB` when I start `B` from `A`, if this flag exists, I just finish, if not, I start `ActivityA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use startActivities() and pass both activities. Android will handle the back stack for you